# Modificar la visibilidad de un Entry, con el estado de un Checkbutton en Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, eventos, callback

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = tkinter.Tk()
caso1_radio = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text= "Caso 1:")
caso1_radio.place(x=0, y=30)
caso1_entry = Entry(root)
caso1_entry.place(x=70, y=30)
caso2_radio = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Caso 2:")
caso2_radio.place(x=0, y=50)
caso2_entry = Entry(root)
caso2_entry.place(x=70, y=50)
root.mainloop()
```

Estoy intentando hacer que los `Entry` aparezcan sólo cuando el `Checkbutton` esté tildado, y si no lo está, que queden ocultos, pero no lo logro.

Lo más cercano que encontré es habilitar o deshabilitar un Entry con un Checkbutton, pero no es exactamente lo que estoy buscando ya que no quiero que el cajón del Entry se muestre si la tilde no está puesta en el check.

¿Cómo puedo tomar el estado del Checkbutton como para poner un condicional y habilitar o no el Entry? ¿O se hace de otra manera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera apropiada de manejar eventos y estados en Tkinter y muchas otras APIs para construir interfaces gráficas es mediante el uso de funciones **callback** o de devolución.

Puedes asociar *callbacks* a la [opción](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm) `command` the `Checkbutton` para que estas funciones definidas según tus objetivos sean invocadas siempre que cambie el estado de la casilla de verificación:

```python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def toggle_entry1():
    if caso1_var.get():
        caso1_entry.place(x=70, y=30)
    else:
        caso1_entry.place_forget()

def toggle_entry2():
    if caso2_var.get():
        caso2_entry.place(x=70, y=50)
    else:
        caso2_entry.place_forget()

root = tk.Tk()

caso1_var = tk.BooleanVar()
caso1_radio = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Caso 1:", variable=caso1_var, command=toggle_entry1)
caso1_radio.place(x=0, y=30)
caso1_entry = tk.Entry(root)

caso2_var = tk.BooleanVar()
caso2_radio = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Caso 2:", variable=caso2_var, command=toggle_entry2)
caso2_radio.place(x=0, y=50)
caso2_entry = tk.Entry(root)

root.mainloop()
```

En este programa, creamos dos [variables](https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-BooleanVar.php) `BooleanVar` para almacenar el **estado** de los Checkbutton y asociamos dichos booleanos con la opción `variable` de `Checkbutton`.

Finalmente, en las *callbacks* `toggle_entry1` y `toggle_entry2` evaluamos si `caso1_var` y `caso2_var` son True o False con su método `get()` y, según el resultado de la evaluación, invocamos los métodos `place()` o `place_forget()` de `Entry` cuyo servicio es evidente.

Comment: Muchas gracias @alejandroMAD. ¿Esto debe hacerse para cada cajón Entry, o existe una manera de formular una sola función que lo haga para todos?

Comment: En programación, una función multiuso casi siempre significa una función parametrizada. Prueba a definir una callback con un parámetro para el widget toggle_visibility(entry) y a llamarla así: command=lambda: toggle_visibility(caso1_entry), etc